# Хочу вынести переменную в которой будут все значения из цикла for

Tags: python

```
def func():
    result = requests.get('https://market.csgo.com/api/v2/items?key=x').json()
    m = len(result['items'])
    for x in range(m):
       id = result['items'][x]['item_id']
func()
```

в `response` есть такие значения как

```
9231923213
9231923212
9231923211
9231923210
```

хочу чтобы все они выводились в переменную id.Как это сделать?

Comment: Переменная id должна быть списком. Добавлять в неё нужные значения с помощь id.append(value)

Comment: Воспользуйтесь советом из комментария выше, только `id` замените на что-то иное. Это имя стандартной функции, нехорошо его использовать.